# How to sum over a multidomentional dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dictionary, how can I sum over all the j with fixed i in x[i,j]

```py
x = {}
x[1,1] = 10
x[1,2] = 20
x[2,1] = 10
x[2,2] = 20
```

Comment: `x[1,1] = 10` creates an entry with a key `(1, 1)` and a value `10`, there's no added depth or extra dimensions. `x[1][1] = 10` seems more like what you want, but won't work until you first create an entry for `x[1]` like `x[1] = {}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am looking at more suitabe data structures.

Comment: you can use `collections.defaultdict(dict)` which will create the second dimension for you on access, and you wouldn't need the middle `x[1] = {}`

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is likely not the right way to represent this data, but if you wanted to use a dict, the structure you describe would be

```
x = {
    1: {
        1: 10,
        2: 20,
    },
    2: {
        1: 20,  # 10 in your original
        2: 30,  # 20 in your original
    }
}
```

To get the sum of all the value under the top-level key `1`:

```
print(sum(x[1].values())) # 10 + 20
```

Though a list of lists seems like the more correct way to represent this. You have to subtract `1` from every index since lists start counting at 0 though:

```
x = [
    [10, 20],  # x[0][0] and x[0][1]
    [20, 30],  # x[1][0] and x[1][1]
]

print(sum(x[0])) # 10 + 20
```

Comment: `print( sum( x[0] )` seems like a perfect answer. Why complicate things by changing suggesting he change the data structure?

Comment: If the indexes are consecutive integers, then a list is almost always a better data structure than a dictionary (it will be faster and have less overhead). The questioner would need to shift to zero-based indexing, but other than that the change would be seamless.

Comment: Oh you are right, he is starting with a `dict` not an `array`. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I misread the question :-(

Comment: I don't have consecutive integers as indexes, this was just for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to sum all `j` for a given `i` in a 2d array of `array[i, j]` then you could create a helper function like so that would sum all `j` for a given `i`.

```
def sum_column(index, data):
    // sum is a built in function - https://devdocs.io/python~3.7/library/functions#sum
    return sum(data[index])
```

However if you want to say, get an array of all sum's of `j` then I would strongly suggest just iterating over it (assuming you know it is a 2d array) rather then bring in any complex dependencies or write any fancy one liners.

For example:

```
def sum_all_columns(data):
    results = []

    for row in data:
        results.append( sum(row) )

    return results
```

Of coarse with a little modification these functions can be updated to support `dict` as well. For example:

```
def sum_column(key, data):
    return sum( data[key].values() )
```